# ajax - How to get the ID of a span element that is created when I select a value by using select2

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the IDs of spans which are inside a form, but I can't seem to find a solution. I am also using select2, here is the code in which I create the spans for every selected value

```
let i = 0;

$('#for-transfer').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  i += 1;

  let data = e.params.data;

  $('<label>').attr({
  class: 'inp',
  for: 'inp'
}).appendTo('#form-for-transfer-inputs');

$('#form-for-transfer-inputs').append("<span id='med-text" + i + "'>" + data.text + "</span>"); //as you can see, there I create the spans

  $('<input>').attr({
  type: 'number',
  id: 'med' + i,
  name: 'med' + i,
  }).appendTo('#form-for-transfer-inputs');

  });
```

And everytime I unselect an element from the multiple-select dropdown, I want to get the IDs so I can delete that span. Below is what I tried last time:

```
$('#for-transfer').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
  let data1 = e.params.data;
  let id = $('span', this).attr('id');
});
```

Please let me know if you need further details

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `:unselect` isn't available. It would be something like `!select2:selected`. Better would be to add an event watcher for `focus` or `blur` to perform whatever action is needed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer! :unselect works fine, I just don't know how to get the ID of the span elements

Comment: Is only one `<span>` selected, or several?

Comment: Several, because as you can see, whenever I select an option, a span is created with a specific id attribute. Whenever I unselect the option, I want to take THAT respective span which is associated with the option

Comment: If you have a number of `<span>` elements in an area, you can select them all and use a `.each` to pull information from each one. `$("span").each(function(){ console.log($(this).attr("id")); });`. If you run that in console on this webpage, you'll likely get nothing because no spans have an `id` attribute. If you change it to target `<div>` for example, you'll get a number of ID strings for all of the various `<div>` tags on this webpage. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: If you want to target only spans under a particular element, for example `#myelement`, you can select the child `<span>` elements. `$("#myelement span").each();`